# How does one do a multisig transaction on EOS?

Tags: wallet, multisig

Is there a way to do multisig transactions on EOS? Which wallets support such a feature to split up a private key and requires all parties to be present before spending it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, multisig is natively supported in the permission model of EOSIO. There used to be [an article](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-nodeos/v1.0.0/docs/accounts-and-permissions) in the official documentation in previous versions, but there doesn't seem to be a page on this yet in the v1.3.0 docs.

However, it is quite straightforward to enable a multisig mechanism on an account. For instance, for a multisig account that requires 2-of-2 signatures for using the `active` permission, you can set the weight threshold required to 2, and the weight of each of the two `active` permissions of the accounts to 1. Thus, to reach the threshold, you'd need both accounts to provide an added weight of 2. This can be done using `cleos` as follows:

```
$ cleos set account permission <multisig-account> active '{"threshold":2,"keys":[],"accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"<first-account>","permission":"active"},"weight":1},{"permission":{"actor":"<second-account>","permission":"active"},"weight":1}],"waits":[]}' owner -p <multi-sig-account>@owner
```

Another example would be setting `<multisig-account>@owner` to reflect a 2-of-3 permission that requires `owner` permissions from at least 2 accounts as below:

```
$ cleos set account permission <multisig-account> owner '{"threshold":2,"keys":[],"accounts":[{"permission":{"actor":"<first-account>","permission":"owner"},"weight":1},{"permission":{"actor":"<second-account>","permission":"owner"},"weight":1},{"permission":{"actor":"<third-account>","permission":"owner"},"weight":1}],"waits":[]}' -p <multi-sig>@owner
```

There are [blog posts](https://steemit.com/eos/@genereos/eos-multisig-tutorial) that attempt to give more examples, and for a more detailed discussion of the ideas of permissions and accounts in EOSIO, the whitepaper has [a section on it](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#role-based-permission-management) and provides a visualisation of the concept as below:

[image: UI diagram from the paper]

---

Beyond working directly with the native permissions system, one could use the [`eosio.msig`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/contracts/eosio.msig) contract that is accessible via the `cleos multisig` subcommand to emulate multisig. This way, one can make proposals that can be reviewed and approved by others. The [README.md](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/tree/master/contracts/eosio.msig) file provides more details on the process.